# DSOFRAMER and 64bit

Tags: c#, 64-bit, dsoframer

We've been using [dsoframer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311765) to embed excel into our .Net app.  Small quicks aside, it works great.  Doesn't seem to work on a 64bit machine though.

Has anyone had any luck with this?  Recompiling the interop/source maybe?  dsoframer is a C++ ActiveX control so this makes sense... just wondering if anyone has done the work already or if I'm missing something.